# C# 3 dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to store ARRAY from 3 dimensional array into buildingCostIds, but it says I MUST have 3rd number.

```
public static int[, ,] buildingCost = { {{0,1,2},{5,5,5}}};

public static void addBuilding(int[] ids, int[] amounts, int buildingId)
{
    int[] buildingCostIds = buildingCost[buildingId, 0, *];
}
```

*I need third number here, but I don't want it because it will extract just number, I want whole array!

PROBLEM SOLVED, solution:

```
public static Array extractArray(int dim1, int dim2)
{
    int[] tempArray = { };

    for (int number=0;number<=2; number++)
    {
    tempArray[number] = buildingCost[dim1, dim2, number];
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```

Comment: Why does the question say C++ and the tag says C#?

Comment: whoops, first time here

Comment: No worries - well done for fixing it

Comment: If you have found a solution, please mark the appropriate answer as accepted (even if that means adding an answer with your solution yourself and marking it as accepted [possibly after waiting for a while](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).

Answer (score 5):

This might be simpler if you use an array-of-arrays, or jagged array `[][][]` like

```
int[][][] buildingCost = new int[2][][];
```

Then you can access `buildingCost[buildingId, 0]` which is an array of ints.

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs)

**EDIT**

Be aware the "problem solved" you added to the question duplicates the data, so you may run out of memory if you keep doing this.
Consider using a List of Lists of Lists and lazy evaluating what you need.

Comment: No, I have much data and I'm lazy to write all them down like that. Found a solution! I'll post it!

Answer (score 2):

Try This

`int[, ,] array3D = new int[3,3,3]`

Comment: How does this help to access the last column?

Comment: lol Stack Overflow rendered it as the `try` and `this` keywords