# Subdivide 3D matrix using Catmull clark algorithm

Tags: c#, math, matrix, interpolation

I am using [Math.net Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) to do calculations with matrices. What I would like is to virtually increase the resolution. I am thinking of subidiving the 3D matrix (representing a surface area) the [Catmull-Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) way. How would I achieve this? I was looking at the [Interpolation namespace](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Interpolate.htm) but did not find anything that could work with a 3d matrix.

Comment: See following there are two solutions int[,,] and int[][][] : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896160/c-sharp-3-dimensional-array

Comment: Catmull-Clark is for explicit surfaces. Does your 3D matrix represent a surface? If so, how? What are you intending to achieve with increasing the resolution?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yes the matrix represents a surface area. Think of it as a 20x20 (WxH) pillars of different height. By increasing the resolution two times, it would become an area of 40x40 pillars. The pillars in between would have a calculated height, just like with Catmull-Clark.

Comment: So you have a 2D matrix instead of a 3D one? Then just treat it as an image and scale it up using a bicubic filter or similar.