# Splitting 2-d array into several 1-d arrays in C#

Tags: c#

I have a 2-d int array say

```
int[,] data = new int[N, numOfCol];
```

Now this is also numOfCol number of 1-d array of length N. Correct?

Suppose numOfCol is 3.

How do we represent those 1-d arrays?

`data[,0] data[,1] and data[,2]` gives me wrong syntax in Visual Studio.

Comment: So, you want to access the second dimension without specifying the first dimension? You can't.

Comment: I think the usage of a jagged array is solution here.

Comment: Go through this Link : http://www.dotnetperls.com/jagged-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your data structure to two dimension array but in format

```
int[][] data = new int[max number of columns][]
```

You could see very good explanation in this post [Multidimensional Array [][] vs [,]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, because your title is about splitting an array, while the body of your question is about the syntax of *declaring* an array.

If you'd like to split a 2D array into a jagged array (i.e. an array of arrays), use something like this:

```
int[,] input = ...

int[][] output = Enumerable.Range(0, input.GetLength(0))
    .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(0, input.GetLength(1))
        .Select(y => input[x, y])
        .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

If all you'd like to do is declare a jagged array, see [Garath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050949/1715579).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I would be cautious next time in defining proper problem statement.

Comment: Lovely. Saved me some time! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    for(int i =0;i<N;i++){
     //in each row

        for(int j=0;j<numOfCol;j++){
         //in each column

          var value = data[i,j]; //like data[0,0] data[0,1] data[0,2].... 
          //you have go through each row and column or directly if
          // you have data in 2nd row and 3rd column, you can write data[1,2]
        }
    }
```