# JavaScript "pushing" arrays into arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here's my relevant code:

```
var data_final = [];
      for(var i = 1; i<4; i++) {
        $.ajax({
          ...
          },
          crossDomain: true,
          success: function(raw_data) {

            // Put the data in the proper array
            for(var d in raw_data.data) {
              data_final[i-1].push([parseDate(d), raw_data.data[d]]);
            }
            data_final[i-1] = twoDimensionalSort(data_final[i-1]);
          }
        });
```

I get an error on this line: `data_final[i-1].push([parseDate(d), raw_data.data[d]]);` that **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"**.

Does the `.push` method not allow one to push an array into an array?  It works fine if I take out the `[i-1]` specification in `data_final`, but I need that to specify where the data should be pushed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: $.ajax is async function and you will not get i's proper value in its callback function.

Comment: What do you mean by that Jeetendra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array

```
var data_final = [];
```

this array is now empty, so doing

```
data_final[i-1]
```

gets you nothing, it's `undefined`, and

```
data_final[i-1].push(something);
```

doesn't work, as you can't push to `undefined`
you should probably just do

```
var arr = [];

for(var d in raw_data.data) {
    arr.push([parseDate(d), raw_data.data[d]]);
}

data_final.push(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
var data_final = [];
for(var i = 1; i<4; i++) {
    if (data_final[i-1] == undefined) data_final[i-1] = [];
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data_final = []
```

You are defining an array. You are getting a value that is *not* an array by indexing it.

The only way this could work is if data_final is a multi-dimensional array:

```
var data_final = [ [], [], [] ];
data_final[0].push([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Technically, those are nested arrays, not multi-dimensional ones.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference to me? I've never heard them used differently before.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12567550/1835379) explains the difference pretty nicely.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can push something into `data_final[]`:

```
       data_final.push("test");
       data_final.push(["pushing","an","array"]);
```

But you cannot actually push anything into an undefined element of the data_final array:

```
       //this will raise an error!!
       data_final[5].push("test");
```

So first you have to initialize each undefined element:

```
       data_final[5] = [];
       data_final[5].push("Now the 5th element is a well defined array");
```

Answer (score -1):

push only appends data to the end of the array, if you would like to put data in a specific place in the array, i recommend that you use splice

view this mdn documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice