# What is the difference between string[][] and string[,]?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, declaration

what is the difference between both of the below declarations ?

```
   private string[][] a = new string[0][];
   private string[,] b = new string[0, 0];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs
This has been asked before. The first may be known as a jagged array, and the latter, a 2 dimensional array

Comment: i didn't know the name of the arrays probably why didnt show in my result when i asked the question. Thanks a lot for your help.