# C# Array Initialization on []

Tags: c#, arrays

So in C# you can define an array like so:

```
string[] Demo;
string[,] Demo;
string[,,] Demo;
```

What does the `,` represent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dimensions.

- No comma: 1 dimension
- 1 comma: 2 dimensions
- 2 commas: 3 dimensions
- and so on...

Learn more about multi-dimensional arrays [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

**Multi-dimensional arrays.**

The following example would declare a string array with two dimensions:

```
string[,] demo = new string[5, 3];
```

The `[,]` syntax is useful, for example, if you have a method taking a 2D array as a parameter:

```
void myMethod(string[,] some2Darray) { ... }
```

Note the difference between multi-dimensional arrays (e.g. `string[,]`), which are like a *matrix*:

```
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
```

and [jagged arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) (e.g. `string[][]`), which are basically arrays of arrays:

```
+------------+
| +-+-+-+-+  |
| | | | | |  |
| +-+-+-+-+  |
+------------+
| +-+-+-+-+  |
| | | | | |  |
| +-+-+-+-+  |
+------------+
| +-+-+-+    |
| | | | |    |  <- possible in jagged arrays but not in multi-dimensional arrays
| +-+-+-+    |
+------------+
```

Reference:

- [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

These are [multi-dimensional arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

The difference between this and `array[][]` as you might be used to is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)