# C# - 2D Array of String Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d, 2d

I am trying to create a world map for a console-based game.

In the World class I have string arrays that can be printed using a level print method.

```
public static string[] A1 = new string[]
{
    (" level data"),
    (" level data"),
};
```

This works if I do

```
Render.DrawLevel(World.A1);
```

where Render.DrawLevel takes args:

```
(string[] _level)
```

However, in the World Class, I want to create a two-dimensional array that can hold all of the Map's string arrays.

I have tried:

```
public static string[,][] Map = new string[,][]
{
    { A1 , A2 },
    { B1 , B2 },
};
```

But if I try to use:

```
World.Map[0,0]
```

as my arguments for level printed, I get given an error that this is `NULL`, instead of the string[] A1.

How can I create a 2d array of arrays, and refer to it properly for string[] arguments?

Thank you very much,

Fin.

EDIT: Incorrectly copied code as 'static void' not just 'static'.

Comment: You are creating a 2 dimensional array of *arrays*. That is, every element of your array is an array itself. An array is a reference type and as such, it's default value is `null`. Think about what happens when you make an array of strings; the elements of the array will be `null` until you assign them a value, well your case is essentially the same thing. You need to initialize every element of `Map[,]` because they will not automatically reference empty arrays as it seems you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you, I made a rookie mistake or assigning variables after referencing them and still expecting them to have the value assigned. This was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `Map` initialization after the initialization of the arrays. A1, A2, B1, B2 are equal to null during the initialization of `Map`.

The syntax is perfectly fine.

This works as intended:

```
    public static string[] A1 = new string[]
        {
            (" level data 1"),
            (" level data 2"),
        };

    public static string[] A2 = new string[]
        {
            (" level data 1"),
            (" level data 2"),
        };

    public static string[] B1 = new string[]
        {
            (" level data 1"),
            (" level data 2"),
        };

    public static string[] B2 = new string[]
        {
            (" level data 1"),
            (" level data 2"),
        };

    public static string[,][] Map = new string[,][]
    {
        { A1, A2 },
        { B1, B2 },
    };
```

Comment: Thank you!I feel silly for not noticing the wrong initialisation order, I was so used to freely-ordered class definitions that I forgot it doesn't work with variable assignment. You have saved me a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A two dimensional array is essentially an array of equally sized arrays. You can visualize it as a matrix, with each column (or row, doesn't really matter) as a separate array. So then the elements in the first row (column) would be the first elements of each of the arrays. What you are doing is trying to create a two dimensional array of arrays.

The best answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs) is a great read concerning your question.

Comment: I have read and re-read this several times. It proved very helpful in my understand of multidimensional arrays. I cannot figure out where the issue of not being able to reference items the array arises.

Comment: The problem was not in the array syntax, but the variable declaration. I hope other will find your link helpful too. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I misinterpreted your code and thought A1 A2 B1 and B2 were strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your signature for Map is incorrect, it can't be void and a multi-dimensional string array. Change it to:

```
    public static string[,][] Map = new string[,][]
        {
            {A1,A2 },
            {B1,B2 },
        };
```

Comment: Thank you, but this was simply a code-copying error and not the actual problem I have. I have edited it now.