# C# - Put two 2D-Arrays in one 3D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to put two `2D`-Arrays in one `3D`-Array, this is my current approach. I am wondering why it isn't working:

```
double[,] l = new double[,]{
    {1,1}
};

double[,] u = new double[,]{
    {2,2}
};
double[,,] lu = new double[,,]
{
    { l },
    { u }
};
```

This also doesn't work:

```
double[,][] lu = new double[,][]
{
    { l }, 
    { u }
};
```

Comment: The problem is your declaration. Try `double[,][]`

Comment: No, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
double[][,] lu = new[] { l,u };
```

Comment: multi dimensional arrays that mix the two array types are horrible though :/

Comment: @will they are and im not entirly sure why its `[][,]`and not `[,][]`

Comment: Why would it be the other way around?

Comment: @CSharpie, MS'es viewpoint, although `[,][]` is more logical for me.

Comment: @will usually its `{TYPE}[]` when declaring arrays. TYPE in this case here is `double[,]`

Comment: What's the language you *think in*?

Comment: @CSharpie i et the `{TYPE}[]` logic, but that's never applied to arrays, regardless of whatever `[][][,,][][,]` madness you want to create.

Comment: @will i never claimed it was, just said i am not sure as to why ms decided to do it like that.

Comment: @CSharpie, the notation allows you to declare arrays in an intuitive way for calling their indexes. If I have `double[][,] a` (array of 2D arrays [these last also called matrixes]) I will know that `a[0]` is the first 2D array of `a`, and that `a[n][0,2]` is the third `double` element of the first row of `a[n]`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs), regarding the difference between multidimensional matrixes (like `double[,]` and `double[,,]`) and arrays of arrays (like `double[][]`).

That being said, `double[][,]` is an array of multidimensional (2D) matrixes, thus each item of it has to be a 2D array, and thus your declaration should be like this:

```
double[][,] lu = new[] { l, u };
```