# What is a byte[][] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

While coding a server, I came across something that I didn't recognize, which is `byte[][]`.

What does this syntax mean, and how do I get rid of the message?

[image]

Comment: It's an array of byte arrays. Why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: It is a [Jagged Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays). Your code (`CopyTo`) shows a List of arrays that is copied to an array of arrays

Comment: It's a jagged byte array (an array of arrays).  You probably don't want to get rid of it as it most certainly serves a purpose even if you're able to detect a code smell about it.  Edit:  lol at all the identical answers posted at the same time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs

Comment: I wasn't aware of what it was, so I figured that it wasn't supposed to be there, but that is extremely helpful. If one of you could put that in an answer, I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Jagged Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) in C#. To be short, it's an Array of Arrays holding bytes.