# How to create an array in constructor that will be used later

Tags: c#, variables, types, constructor, global-variables

I am making a Matrix class and want to make the constructor input the Matrix type too. How can I initialize a specific type 2d array?

```
public class Matrix
    {
        public int[][] matrix;
        //??


        Matrix(int x,int y,string type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case "int":
                    //initialize a int 2d array
                case "double":
                    //initialize a double 2d array
                case "float":
                    //initialize a float 2d array
                default:
                   //initialize a float 2d array
                   break;

           }

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics with a constraint of `new` might help, if the type can be declared at design time

```
public class Matrix<T> where T : new()
{
   public T[][] matrix;
   public Matrix(int x, int y)
      => matrix = Enumerable.Range(0,x).Select(elem => new T[y]).ToArray();    
}
```

**Usage**

```
var something = new Matrix<int>(4,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard approach would be to use generics instead of string name of the type like `Matrix<T>`.

If you want to specify type as string at run-time you have to either add multiple fields to store each type of an array or use `dynamic` or `object` as the type of array (since you can't assign `float[][]` to field of type `int[][]`).

For non-performance sensitive code I'd go with `dynamic` as it will give you code that looks reasonable (you loose intellisense and compile time safety) and validates all operations at run-time anyway.

```
public class Matrix
{
    dynamic matrix;

    Matrix(int x,int y,string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "int":
                matrix = 
                   Enumerable.Repeat(0, x).Select(_ => new int[y]).ToArray();
                break;
            case "double":
                //initialize a double 2d array
                matrix = 
                   Enumerable.Repeat(0, x).Select(_ => new double[y]).ToArray();
                break;
            case "float":
            default:
                //initialize a float 2d array
                matrix = 
                   Enumerable.Repeat(0, x).Select(_ => new float[y]).ToArray();
                break;
         }
     }
 }
```

For array initialization see [Multidimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567404/477420) question.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

```
public class Matrix<T> 
{    
    public T[,] matrix;

    public Matrix<T>(int x, int y)
    {
        matrix = new T[x, y];
    }
}
```

You can probably find an existing, well-tested Matrix class somewhere on the internet.

Comment: Same answer as Michael's, except you are showing some other array type than OP asked for - sample code shows Jagged Array (which they probably by mistake call 2d array)