# C#: How to access values from Object[ , ]

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using EPPlus for reading excel file and I got all excel rows and columns where data is present as `Object[,]`

[image]

I tried to access individual values using `data[0,0]` but it fails.

**How can I access the individual values in this `Object[,]` ?**

Comment: Has any of this topics answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays

Comment: @PeterCsala I got it from the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it like

```
var data = worksheet.Cells[0,0].Value;
```

So you need to define the index at cell level, not at value level.

Since `ExcelWorksheet.Cells.Value` is of type `object`, you first need to cast to `object[,]` if you are trying to access on value level:

```
var data = ((object[,])worksheet.Cells.Value)[0,0];
```

Comment: `Error CS0022 Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2`

Comment: I don't want to access `Cell[1,1]` as I don;t know if they will have data. That is why I want to access using `worksheet.Cells.Value` way

Comment: See the extended answer.