# visual representation of arrays с#

Tags: c#, arrays

[image: visual representation of arrays]

did I visualize 1D and 2D arrays correctly? if so, can you help with rendering a 3D and toothed array in this style?

Comment: A 3D array is an array of 2D arrays, just as a 2D array is an array of 1D arrays; draw accordingly.

Comment: I wonder if the pictures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs) will help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `c#` stores 2D arrays in row-major form (row by row). So the graphic looks correct.